# Not able to import module after installing using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, ip-address, compass-geolocation

Im trying to import a module called geoip2 from pypi into python it is not included in its standard libraries.

I open command prompt and type:

```
pip install geoip2
```

The command prompt returns

```
Successfully installed geoip2-2.4.2
```

After it is installed I try importing it using IDLE:

```
import geoip2.webservice
```

which returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import geoip2.webservice
ImportError: No module named 'geoip2'
```

Although it is installed already I cannot use it. How can i prevent this? Take note that I use python 3.6

Comment: what is the output when you type `pip show geoip2` ? Does it show that was installed correctly?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `pip3 install geoip2`?

Comment: firstly check that module is installed or not using `pip freeze`

Comment: @turtle it is working in my case. I think you geoip2 is not installed correctly. You can do one thing create virtualenv first by command virtualenv <virtual_env_name>. then activate that environment. and in that pip install geoip2 then run that statement in python shell it will not give any error.

Answer (score 1):

May be you have two different version of Python installed. Try opening IDLE using the Python version where you have installed geoip.

Comment: even after trying 'import geoip2' the shell returns an error as it cant find the module

Comment: when opening python in cmd i can import geoip2 but i cant in the shell or interpreter

Comment: It happens when you use idle in one version like Python2.x and use pip to install packages in another version like Python3.x.So make sure that you have only one version of Python is installed.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

`import geoip2.webservice`

Try doing:

```
import geoip2
from geoip2 import webservice
```

Since `geoip2.webservice` is not installed, `geopip2` is and `.webservice` is an function object of that module.

Further, you can avoid typing `geoip2.webservice` every time by doing:

```
import geoip2
from geoip2 import webservice as gws
```

Then anytime you want to run the `.webservice` function, you can just use `gws`.

**Alternatively:**

Just do:

`import geoip2`

Then in your script you can call it:

`geoip2.webservice(#do stuff here or however you call the function)`

Comment: try import geoip2.webservice it will not give any error and as u said webservice is an object of that module so that is not just check by type that is a module you can see that module in your virtual environment also.